# Regular expression using '$' sign and '^'

Tags: regex

Can some body explain the difference between below expressions please?

`[0-9]{1,3}:[0-5][0-9]`

`^([0-9]{1,3}:[0-5][0-9])$`

I don't get the exact usage of ^ sign and $ sign in regular expressions.

I observe that If I write the second expression as below, it didn't make any difference.

`^([0-9]{1,3}):([0-5][0-9])$`

Comment: The first one will match any string that _contains_ 3 digits followed by a : followed by a digit less than 6 followed by a digit.  The second will match only strings which contain that and ONLY that.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

examples explain it clear:

```
^     : matches the beginning of a line
$     : matches the end of a line

"^foo$" : matches "foo", but not " foo" or "xxfooyy"
"foo$"  : matches "foo",  " foo" or "xxfoo" but not "foobar"
"^foo"  : matches "foo",  "fooyy" or "foo " but not "xfoo"
"foo"   : matches "foo",  " foo" or "xxfooyy"
```

Answer (score 2):

`^` and `$` are here [the start and end of string anchors](http://www.regular-expressions.info/anchors.html).

The second regular expression means you want to match the whole input.

Answer (score 2):

`^` = start of string/line
`$` = end of string/line

So your first expression will also match "FOO123:12BAR"

The difference between your second and third expression is not in what they *match* but what they *capture*, as the parantheses for capture groups differ.